# Check how many people are within a certain distance from the center

Tags: java, bukkit

I'm making a Spleef plugin.
I need to count the amount of people in a lobby.

I thought that I could count how many people are within a certain distance from the center of the lobby.
I think that this may work better than recording when someone types the command.

*Main.java:*

```
package me.olsyboy.spleef;

import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.ChatColor;
import org.bukkit.Location;
import org.bukkit.World;
import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;
import org.bukkit.configuration.file.YamlConfiguration;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Main extends JavaPlugin {
    public void onEnable(int amountOfPlayers) {
        amountOfPlayers = 0;
        loadConfiguration();
        reloadConfig();
    }

    public void onDisable() {
        saveDefaultConfig();
    }

    public void loadConfiguration() {
        //See "Creating you're defaults"
        getConfig().options().copyDefaults(true); // NOTE: You do not have to use "plugin." if the class extends the java plugin
        //Save the config whenever you manipulate it
        saveDefaultConfig();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String label, String[] args) {
        Player player = (Player) sender;
        if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("spleef")) {
            if (args[0].equalsIgnoreCase("setgame")) {
                if (args.length == 2) {
                    String gameName = args[1]; //initialize the gameName variable here
                    getConfig().set("Game Locations." + gameName + ".Location", Arrays.asList(player.getLocation().getX(), player.getLocation().getY(), player.getLocation().getZ(), player.getLocation().getPitch(), player.getLocation().getYaw(), player.getLocation().getWorld().getName()));
                    getConfig().options().copyDefaults(true);
                    saveConfig();
                    player.sendMessage(ChatColor.AQUA + "[Spleef] " + ChatColor.YELLOW + "Spleef Game Location Set");
                }
            }
            if (args[0].equalsIgnoreCase("join")) {
                String gameName = args[1]; //initialize the gameName variable here
                List<String> joinGameLocation = this.getConfig().getStringList("Game Locations." + gameName + ".Location");
                String xPos = joinGameLocation.get(0);
                double xPos2 = Double.parseDouble(xPos);

                String yPos = joinGameLocation.get(1);
                double yPos2 = Double.parseDouble(yPos);

                String zPos = joinGameLocation.get(2);
                double zPos2 = Double.parseDouble(zPos);

                String pitch = joinGameLocation.get(3);
                float pitch2 = Float.parseFloat(pitch);

                String Yaw = joinGameLocation.get(4);
                float Yaw2 = Float.parseFloat(Yaw);

                World actualWorld = Bukkit.getWorld(joinGameLocation.get(5));
                Location spleefGameLocation = new Location(actualWorld, xPos2, yPos2, zPos2);
                spleefGameLocation.setPitch(pitch2);
                spleefGameLocation.setYaw(Yaw2);
                player.teleport(spleefGameLocation);
            }
            else if (!(args[0].equalsIgnoreCase("setgame"))) {
                if (!args[0].equalsIgnoreCase("join")) {
                    player.sendMessage("/spleef join {GameName}");
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

*playerJoinedGame.java:*

```
package me.olsyboy.spleef;

public class playerJoinedGame extends Main {
    public void onPlayerJoin(int amountOfPlayers)
    {
        amountOfPlayers = amountOfPlayers + 1;
    }
}
```

I have not called the `onPlayerJoin` method from the main class yet.

I'm open to anyone having any better ways of counting the amount of people in a lobby.

Comment: Just an extra note on your practices for counting players. First of all, a helpful tip: use "amountOfPlayers+=1" or "amountOfPlayers++", this will increment a numerical field (Integers, doubles, floats, etc.) in a cleaner way. Another way of getting the live of amount of players on the server: Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers().length; or Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers.size(); (depending on the version you are using). You can use this in some sort of Runnable or using the PlayerJoin/PlayerQuit events.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you have a `Location` object with the center of which you want to get the nearby players.

```
Location center = new Location(world, x, y, z);
```

Then, have a `double` value with the needed distance.

```
double distance = 10D;
```

First of all, you should make a loop of all players on the server:

```
for (Player player : Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers()) {

}
```

Then, get the location of `player`:

```
for (Player player : Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers()) {
    Location location = player.getLocation();
}
```

Now we can do a check of the distance between the two locations (`center` and `location`):

```
for (Player player : Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers()) {
    Location location = player.getLocation();
    if (location.distanceSquared(center) <= distance * distance) {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

**Notice:** You should use `distanceSquared(Location)` which is equivalent to the result square of `distance(Location)`, because `distance(Location)` uses Java's square-root method, which is very resource-heavy.

Final result:

```
double distance = 10D;
Location center = new Location(Bukkit.getWorld("world"), x, y, z);

for (Player player : Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers()) {
    Location location = player.getLocation();
    if (location.distanceSquared(center) <= distance * distance) {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to multiply `distance` by itself?

Comment: Because distanceSquared() returns a squared value of the distance. Since we do not want to use the distance() method (which makes use of the square root operation), it is better to compare distances using a squared value and the distanceSquared() method. This has minimal effects on small-scale situations, but is still a better practice. - Using distance() can make the server lag if abused.

Comment: Just read https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/spigot/org/bukkit/Location.html#distance(org.bukkit.Location) and https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/spigot/org/bukkit/Location.html#distanceSquared(org.bukkit.Location) .

Answer (score 0):

```
loc.getWorld().getNearbyEntities(loc, distance, distance, distance).stream()
        .filter(e -> e instanceof Player)
        .findFirst()
        .orElse(null);
```

Just do this

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.